# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reference' of undefined - google places library api

Tags: javascript, css, google-places-api

I am having this error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reference' of undefined

I am using the google places api javascript library.

All I am working on is an autocomplete search bar and when selected I would like to grab coordinates and place name
I have worked on this stuff before and are literally using the same script on another page and it works perfectly.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>

function initialize() {  
var mapOptions = {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2195),
zoom: 13,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
mapOptions);

var input = document.getElementById('bookings_searchbar_place');
var options = {
types: ['(cities)']
};
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {

 var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

alert(place.reference);

});
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

and the other code in the file connected to a seperate searchbar which works fine.

```
function initialize() {  
var mapOptions = {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2195),
zoom: 13,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
mapOptions);

var input = document.getElementById('searcherbar');
var options = {
types: ['(cities)']
};
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {

var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

alert(place.reference);
alert(place.reference);    

var locc = str_replace(' ' , '' , place.geometry.location);
var locc2 = str_replace(',' , '_' , locc);
var locc3 = str_replace('-' , '@' , locc2);
var locc4 = str_replace('(' , '' , locc3);
var locc5 = str_replace(')' , '' , locc4);

var location_lat = str_replace('(' , '' , place.geometry.location);
var location_lat2 = str_replace(')' , '' , location_lat);
var location_lat3 = location_lat2.split(",");

var formatted_address1 = str_replace(',', '@', $('#searcherbar').val());
var formatted_address2 = str_replace(' ', '-', formatted_address1);

//window.location="area.php?id="+formatted_address2+"&loc="+locc5;  


});
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


<input id='bookings_searchbar_place' type='text' placeholder=""/>

<div style='display:none;' id='map-canvas'></div>

<input id='searcherbar' type='text' placeholder=""/>

<div style='display:none;' id='map_canvas'></div>
```

Comment: Your script works as-is for me, as long as the JavaScript is enclosed in `<script>...</script>`.  Is there other code or HTML on your page?

Comment: yes there is other code although does it get the place.reference for you? and is there any error in the console? thanks for helping.

Comment: No error in console, and I get a reference that looks something like this:  CoQBfgAAABBtQbei...    Works in Chrome, IE, Firefox, and Safari.  There may be something else in the code that's interfering.

Comment: im adding the other code in the script now, have a look in a minute

Comment: ok i have added the other code in the script

Comment: I get an error that str_replace is undefined.  Are you linking in any other JS files?

Comment: yeah sorry i have that file included str_replace.js

Comment: Thanks, I'll assume str_replace matches http://phpjs.org/functions/str_replace/, and I assume jQuery is linked in because of `$('#searcherbar')`.  If so, I get no console error messages, and I do get the `place.reference` string in an alert.